# How to pass a list of of variables to a function but also considering quosures and quoting

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I'd like to pass a list of variables to a function, but I'm confused by the quoting and quosures.

Normally, I want to return a df after some kind of data management has been done--after the function has been applied to several variables.

As it is the function works ok (just slightly modified from a users stack exchange [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088528/use-select-helpers-with-dplyrcoalesce) to another question), but the calls are repetitive in this example. Any suggestions, points to readings or etc., I'd appreciate.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
library(tidyselect)

data <- data.frame(ageeeeoo = c(1,NA,3,NA,5), 
                   ageeeaah = c(NA,2,NA,4,NA),
                   numnumd  = c(1,NA,3,NA,5),
                   numfoofe = c(NA,2,NA,4,NA))



newfun <- function (var1) {

var1<-enquo(var1)
data<<-mutate(data,(!!as_name(var1)) := coalesce(!!! syms(vars_select(names(data), 
                                       starts_with(as_name(var1))))))
}


newfun(age)
newfun(num)



  ageeeeoo ageeeaah numnumd numfoofe age num
        1       NA       1       NA   1   1
       NA        2      NA        2   2   2
        3       NA       3       NA   3   3
       NA        4      NA        4   4   4
        5       NA       5       NA   5   5
```

I tried reviewing the dplyr programming documents and a few other stack exchange [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993471/tidyeval-with-list-of-column-names-in-a-function?rq=1) but the quoting throws me off. I've tried using alist and list but get errors.

```
listofvars<-c("age","num")

newfun <- function (...) {

data<<-mutate(data,(!!!rlang::syms(...)) := coalesce(!!! syms(vars_select(names(data),
                                            starts_with(!!!quos(...))))))
}


  newfun(listofvars)
```

Comment: bueller...bueller...bueller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
library(tidyselect)

data <- data.frame(ageeeeoo = c(1,NA,3,NA,5), 
                   ageeeaah = c(NA,2,NA,4,NA),
                   numnumd  = c(1,NA,3,NA,5),
                   numfoofe = c(NA,2,NA,4,NA))



newfun2 <- function (data, ...) {

  vars <- ensyms(..., .named = TRUE)
  needed <- map(
    vars,
    ~vars_select(names(data), starts_with(as_name(.x))) %>% 
    {quo(coalesce(!!!syms(.)))}
  )
  mutate(data, !!!needed)
}

data <- newfun2(data, age, num)

list_of_vars <- exprs(age, num)
data <- newfun2(data, !!!list_of_vars)
data
```

This first captures the input from `...` as symbols. It can uses `purrr::map` to generate a list of `coalesce` operations. These are then supplied to `mutate`. I’ve rewritten the code so as not to modify the global environment within a function; most R code works like this, so in general variables won’t be altered except by explicit assignment.

The rlang help and [Hadley Wickham’s advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) are great resources.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had been playing with it for a little while and couldn't get the quoting correct.  I'll keep reviewing the resources you suggested. The use of ensyms is interesting to me and that mutate is called separately. I've been dragging my feet learning purrr::map and this will be a good example to study. Thank you!